# Saving data form without button

Tags: javascript, forms, user-experience

What is a good way of saving data form without submit button?

I have one idea. Below exemplary source code.

```
var delay = 1000,
       timeId,
       ajax,
       //fw is some framework
       form = fw.get('myform');

form.getFields().on('change', changeEventHandler);

function changeEventHandler() {
    clearTimeout(timeId);
    timeId = setTimeout(this.ajaxRequest, delay);
}

function ajaxRequest() {
    //What do with old ajax request? Abort it?
    ajax = fw.ajax({
       url: 'ololo',
       params: {
           data: form.getValues()
      }
   });
}
```

What do with old ajax request? Abort it?

Have somebody other ideas?

Comment: Whether calling `fw.ajax()` a second time replaces pending requests or appends a new one depends on what it's designed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem when designed an interactive form without save button.

First of all, its not a good idea to save the data on every change. I used on blur event, so when the input loses focus, I check if the value was changed (i.e. not just focus-blur on the input), if it was changed, I disabled the input and send an ajax request. When the request returned, I enabled the input once again (possibly displaying an error if the ajax failed and etc, depends on your needs).

Its the easiest way to do interactive form. This avoids the headache of multiple request trying to modify the same value on server side and the headache of monitoring all ajax requests.

Comment: If user will close a window? And event blur of fields do not work, after i focus on other components of my ui.

Comment: This is the price you have to pay. Any Ajax call that saves data might be interrupted by user closing the browser. If you want to can have a global var that says if there is an Ajax request going, and if so - display an alert message when user closes the browser window. Personally - I hate sites doing so. On the other hand, updating the DB on every character the user changes, is also not a good idea. And blur event should work every time the element loses focus.

Comment: Blur event do not work only when i focus on map container (i use leaflet js).

P.S. My app is RIA.